# Which type of subscription to use?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a `client-server` app that communicates with a backend where user can register an account.

The app must allow user to purchase a monthly subscription to enable some additional features `(creating unlimited "stuffs" and automatic conversion between some currencies)`.

I need the purchased subscription to be bound to a single user account on my backend, so for instance if a single Apple user registers two accounts on my backend, I'd only allow to have additional features to the account that user was logged in under when they made a subscription. If possible, I'd like to allow subscribing to every account from my backend that has no subscription.

After spending a few days researching this, I'm still confused -

should I use **auto-renewing** or **non-renewing** subscription for this?

How do I bind a subscription to an account on my backend?

Answer (score 0):

There only one method for purchasing an additional functionality of your application. which is `In-App-Purchase`.

Many iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Mac apps allow you to buy `subscriptions` or `extra content` (such as in-game currency, a full game unlock, or bonus content) in the app.

If you are trying to add other method like `STRIPE`, `PAYPAL`, `PAYU` and etc. Then you application will be discarded from the Apple application reviewer. You can never live your application on apple store.
So apple insist you for you using only In-App-Purchase.

> `auto-renewing subscription` means that it will automatically renew after a given time of periods like it may be 1 month, 6 month or any other option.
>
> `non-renewing subscription` means that there is only one time fees to the user and they can use unlimited functionality for the unlimited time.

When you will use `In-App-Purchase` in your application so Apple will give you receipt which you need to check for  `auto-renewing subscription`. is user has canceled your subscription or not. You can follow [that link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)  for receipt validation.

So Follow this tutorials :- https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case, you should opt for auto-renewing subscription. When the user purchases an item from your app, Apple gives a receipt that you can store as an additional field in your user database.

On app load, you can verify this receipt with Apple. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1). You can also check your database when the user logs in if they have purchased anything and show appropriate options on the UI.